# How to replace from second occurrence

Tags: regex, textpad

My data looks like this:

```
Name,Minutes,Meters
ABILENE TX - CHARLESTON SC - ABILENE TX - CHARLESTON SC,1162,2052516
ABILENE TX - CHARLESTON WV - ABILENE TX - CHARLESTON WV,1153,2029119
ABILENE TX - LAFAYETTE IN - ABILENE TX - LAFAYETTE IN,1040,1809812
```

I need to replace from the second hyphen to the first comma, with only a comma.
I'm using Textpad.

I want it to look like this:

```
ABILENE TX - CHARLESTON SC,1162,2052516
ABILENE TX - CHARLESTON WV,1153,2029119
```

Comment: Your question might be clearer if you also show an example of what you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by replacing

```
|\n[^\-]*\- |
```

with

```
\n
```

and running it twice.